# Как заменить динамический полиморфизм статическим?

Tags: c++

Допустим, у нас есть несколько классов

```
class A{
  double r(){ return 2.; }
  void p(){ std::cout << "Hello!"; }
};

class B{
  char r(){ return '2'; }
  void p(){ std::cout << "Hello!"; }
};

class C{
  int r(){ return 2; }
  void p(){ std::cout << "Hello!"; }
};
```

Для статического полиморфизма обычно (или не обычно) используют std::variant

```
std::variant<A, B, C> vars[3] = {A{}, B{}, C{}};
```

Теперь, использую паттерн 'посетитель', мы можем написать лямбда функцию, которая будет вызывать метод **p()**

```
auto invoke_p = [](auto& el){
  el.p();
};
```

Теперь мы можем спокойно пройти по всему массиву и 'посетить' каждый вариант:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
  std::visit(invoke_p, vars[i]);
}
```

Всё кажется простым, пока не нужно получить что-то из варианта.

```
template <size_t N>
class num{
  std::array<size_t, n> value;
};

class A{
  num<1> r(){ return {}; }
  void p(){ std::cout << "Hello!"; }
};

class B{
  num<2> r(){ return {}; }
  void p(){ std::cout << "Hello!"; }
};

class C{
  num<3> r(){ return {}; }
  void p(){ std::cout << "Hello!"; }
};

std::variant<A, B, C> vars[3] = {A{}, B{}, C{}};

size_t sum = 0;

for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
  auto tmp = std::visit(invoke_p, vars[i]);
  for(auto n: tmp){
    std::cout << n;
  }
}
```

Тут начинаются проблемы, возвращаемый тип всегда разный, я не знаю, какой должен быть подход, чтобы красиво и грамотно решить эту проблему. Может есть какой-то паттерн или статический полиморфизм подходит только для посетителя. (если вообще я правильно называю это статическим полиморфизмом, если нет, то поправьте и спасибо за понимание, я новичок)

**Правка**

У меня есть классы: пирамида, призма, тетраэдр и тд. У каждого элемента есть грань, она может быть 3х угольником или 4х угольником. Каждый угол грани это 3d точка.

И вот, к примеру, мой кусок кода, который я написал так-как-смог

```
static auto get_nodes = [&](auto& el1, auto& el2, auto& el3, auto& el4) {
  for (auto f1 : el1.get_m_faces()) {
    for (auto f2 : el2.get_m_faces()) {
      for (auto f3 : el3.get_m_faces()) {
        if(f1 == f2 && f2 == f3){
          // очень важная работа
        }
      }
    }
 };
```

Мне не нравится то, что пришлось сделать лямбда-функцию, которая принимает несколько объектов.

Вместо этого я бы хотел что-то такое:
(Тут el1, el2, el3 это **std::variant**)

```
std::vector<.....> v;

for (size_t i = 0; i < el1.get_m_faces().size(); ++i) {
    v.emplace_back(std::visit(получить грань номер i));
    // Не знаю, как в std::visit передать номер грани дополнительным аргументом
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < el2.get_m_faces().size(); ++i) {
    v.emplace_back(std::visit(получить грань номер i));
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < el3.get_m_faces().size(); ++i) {
    v.emplace_back(std::visit(получить грань номер i));
}

// дальше найти одинаковые, так сложность алгоритма будет не O(n^3), а O(3n) с копейками
// Но тогда std vector должен тоже хранить **variant** или **any**
```

Да и мне вообще интересно, как правильно решать задачи, когда нужно что-то **получить** из таких структур. Или правильным решением будет - всеми силами этого избегать?

Comment: А какую конкретно задачу Вы пытаетесь решить? От этого может сильно зависеть ответ. И новички обычно не пишут с применением visit+variant+шаблоны (к стати, в коде есть ошибки)

Comment: Добавил правку.

Comment: Мое *личное*, ни к чему не обязывающее мнение - если мы видим `variant` (в существенно меньшей степени - `optional`), то это скорее признак smell code/design - не совсем продуманное решение... Да, и в моем представлении называть это статическим полиморфизмом - т.е. разрешением типов во время компиляции - как-то не совсем корректно. Опять же - чисто мое личное мнение, никого ни к чему не обязывающее...

Comment: optional, который скрывает голый указатель, это часто просто удобно. а variant вместо union. Но здесь больше похоже на питоновский код.

Comment: Иногда я мечтаю, чтобы пол года назад меня взяли на позицию junior, чтобы не мучаться сейчас и не продумывать дизайн всего кода. Продумывал бы кто нибудь другой, а я пузырьковую сортировку писал бы сидел, эх...

Comment: а на какую же позицию взяли?

Comment: Для статического полиморфизма обычно используют шаблоны. А во втором примере не видно нужды ни в классах *пирамида, призма, тетраэдр и тд*, ни в лямбах, ни в variant или any. Всю эту геометрию можно хранить и обрабатывать как vector<point>. Variant удобен, как раз когда нужно вернуть объект одного из нескольких разных типов, например поле json.

Comment: взяли на никакую позицию) дали проект и делаю его в одно лицо :(

Comment: Всю эту геометрию можно хранить и обрабатывать как vector<point>. - Такой вариант уже реализован, но с ним очень медленно код пишется, каждый раз приходится написать кучу строк, чтобы восстановить какое нибудь ребро, а в моём варианте это всё в пару строк пишется и легче читается. Из-за того, что я один, это ускоряет процесс написания, но, правда, немного замедляет саму программу

Comment: Ну значит это типичная проблема XY... Задавайте вопрос о самом затруднении, а не о своей попытке его преодолеть.

Answer (score 2):

с++ это не питон или другой язык с динамической типизацией. Нельзя просто так взять и возвратить что попало и надеяться, что компилятор с этим справится. К сожалению, принцип [AAA](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) разбаловал новичков...

Пойдем в строку кода

```
auto tmp = std::visit(invoke_p, vars[i]);
```

тут Вы надеетесь, что `visit` проявит недюжинные способности и возвратит что то, по чему можно итерироваться. А он так не умеет. Совсем. Это не хаскелевский `map`/`fmap`. Плюс ко всему, то, что в `tmp` лежит должно иметь иметь разные типы у каждого элемента. `variant`? Гетерогенный вектор? есть туплы (std::tuple), но так красиво с ними не выйдет.

Но когда шаблоны пасуют (потому что они не нужны в данном случае), на помощь приходит обычный классический с++. Я набросал чуточку кода, тут конечно явно не хватает get'ров и set'еров со скрытием публичных вещей, и наверно пары функций-удобняшек, что бы сократить наполнение, но это Вам будет виднее, как переделать, а мне идею показать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// храним одну точку. но может использовать glm::vec3
struct Point
{
        float x,y,z;
};

//что бы легко было выводить в консоль (например, для отладки)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p) {
    os << "[" << p.x << "," << p.y << "," << p.z << "]";
    return os;
}

// храним грани
struct Face
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Point> points;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Face& f) {
    os << "[";
    for (Point p : f.points) {
        os << p << " ";
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}

struct Shape {
        std::vector<Face> faces;
        virtual void show() = 0;
};

class Cube: public Shape
{
    public:
        Cube() {
            faces.resize(6);
            faces[0].name = "First";
            faces[0].points.push_back({0,0,0});
            faces[0].points.push_back({0,0,1});
            faces[0].points.push_back({0,1,1});
            faces[0].points.push_back({0,1,0});

        }
        void show() override
        {
            std::cout << "I'm Cube\n";
        }
};

class Tetrahedron : public Shape
{
    public:
        Tetrahedron()
        {
            faces.resize(4);
        }
        void show() override
        {
            std::cout << "I'm Tetrahedron\n";
        }
};


int main()
{
    // используем shared_ptr, что бы избежать хранения указателей и ручного управления памятью.
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> shapes;
    shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Cube>());
    shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Tetrahedron>());
    // спросим, кто они
    for (auto& sh : shapes) {
        sh->show();
        std::cout << "I have " << sh->faces.size() << " faces\n";
    }

    // сделаем пробежку по внутренностям
    for (auto& sh : shapes) {
        sh->show();
        for (auto& f : sh->faces) {
            std::cout << f.name << " face\n";
            std::cout << f << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

и отвечая на вопрос в заголовке "Как заменить динамический полиморфизм статическим?" - а зачем?

Comment: У меня уже есть рабочий код с динамическим полиморфизмом, мне надоело туда-сюда кастовать, узнавать, что за тип лежит и тд. К тому же не получается реализовать функцию, которая у одного объекта возвращает грань из 3х точек, а у другого из 4х, потому что перегруженные функции должны быть одинаковыми

Comment: Если Вам нужно "узнавать какой тип лежит", это значит, что в базовом классе нужно сделать виртуальную функцию. А ещё узнать о [двойной диспетчеризации](https://habr.com/ru/post/259031/)

Comment: И еще узнать, что переопределенные (а не перегруженные наверно:) ) могут возвращать разные типы. Главное, что бы у этих типов был один базовый предок (называется ковариантность)