# Универсальная функция для заполнения вектора std::variant

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонный класс,

```
template <size_t Num>
class some{
  int value[Num];
};
```

экземпляры которого мы будем хранить в векторе с помощью std::variant

```
std::vector<std::variant<some<3>, some<4>, some<8>>> v;
```

Теперь мне захотелось написать функцию, которая считывает данные из файла, которые записаны в следующем формате:

| Кол-во элементов | Элементы |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 2 3 |
| 4 | 32 1 30 98 |

Собственно вот и она:

```
 static void read(path p) {
   size_t num_elements;
   std::fstream input_file(p);
   ElementCreator<3> creator3;
   ElementCreator<4> creator4;
   ElementCreator<8> creator8;

   input_file >> num_elements;
   for (size_t ne = 0; ne < num_elements; ++ne) {
        input_file >> num_points_in_element;

        if (num_points_in_element == 3) {
          for (size_t np = 0; np < num_points_in_element; ++np) {
            input_file >> index;
            creator3.add_index(index);
          }

          v.emplace_back(creator3.get());
          creator3.clear();
        } else if (num_points_in_element == 4) {
          for (size_t np = 0; np < num_points_in_element; ++np) {
            input_file >> index;
            creator4.add_index(index);
          }

          v.emplace_back(creator4.get());
          creator4.clear();
        } else if (num_points_in_element == 8) {
          for (size_t np = 0; np < num_points_in_element; ++np) {
            input_file >> index;
            creator8.add_index(index);
          }

          v.emplace_back(creator8.get());
          creator8.clear();
        }
   }
```

Класс-создатель

```
template <size_t N>
struct ElementCreator {
  public:
    using element_type = some<N>;

  public:
    ~ElementCreator() = default;

  public:
    ElementCreator(const ElementCreator&)           = delete;
    ElementCreator(ElementCreator&&)                = delete;
    ElementCreator operator=(const ElementCreator&) = delete;
    ElementCreator operator=(ElementCreator&&)      = delete;

  public:
    ElementCreator()
      : _element(element_type{}){
    }

    void add_index(size_t index) {
      _element._value[_n] = index;
      ++_n;
    }


    const element_type& get() const {
      return _element;
    }

    void clear() {
      _element = element_type{};
    }

  private:
    element_type _element;
    size_t _n = 0;
};
```

**Ой, как прекрасно! - подумал глупый программист.**

Оказывается, что это работает только тогда, когда в векторе **v** и в функции **read** все типы совпадают. Если я захочу сделать вектор только из типов **some<3>** и **some<4>**, то это уже не скомпилируется, придётся убрать из функции часть кода для some<8>, то есть переписать её.

Глупый программист делает выводы:

- Нельзя написать функцию с if-ами для каждого типа сразу (у меня их около 10)
- Писать для каждого возможного варианта типов (перебором) это ∑(k = 1-10) n!/(k!(n-k)!) = 1 + 10 + 45 + 120 + 210 + 252 + 210 + 120 + 45 + 10 = очень много - я умру столько писать.

*Давайте поможем ему не сделать еще одну ошибку и спасём мир от очередного самописного костыля.*

Comment: Делайте `::std::vector<int>` и вектор со смещениями, `variant` не нужен.

Comment: это попытка впихнуть странный код для вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286219/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc   - а типы все вида `some<число>` ?

Comment: вы меня поймали. Да, типы все такого вида

Comment: так используйте вектор. И всех делов то. Или сделайте обертку вокруг него, если нужны дополнительные данные.

Comment: Так нельзя же, типы some<1> и some<2> - разные

Comment: показывайте собственно, что такое some.

Comment: В самом верху, она в упрощенном виде, в проекте это структура с массивом из n чисел и два функтора

Comment: И кто мешает вместо этого использовать вектор? Или Вы скрываете реальный тип, или Вы просто хотите упорно использовать только шаблоны

Comment: Ох, ощущение у меня, что вы выясняете, какой рукой держать отвертку при забивании гвоздей и упорно не хотите спросить о молотке...

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас задам новый вопрос о молотке)

Comment: закрывайте вопрос о молотке. Потому что он не приносит ничего нового, что бы мы не знали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1287080/c-%d0%a5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0